# xsl generation of html table wirh a button for every row

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, xslt-1.0

i have a problem and i hope somebody can help me.

Here is a shortened part of my xsl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function anAus(id) 
        {
                    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') 
                    { document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
                } else 
                    { document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';}
            }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<TABLE border="1">

<thead>
<TH>[ id ]</TH>
<TH>[ name ]</TH>
<TH>[ aktiv ]</TH>
<TH>[ result ]</TH>
<TH>[ help ]</TH>
</thead>

<tbody>
<xsl:for-each select="....." >

<TR>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></TD>   
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="name" /></TD> 
    <TD> <xsl:value-of select="@activated" /></TD>
    <TD><xsl:value-of select="result" /></TD>

     <!-- column 5 --- Button -->
    <xsl:variable name="button_name" select="concat('Button_',$ID)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="button_variable" select="concat('but_var',$ID)"/>

    <TD width="50" align="center"><input name="$button_name"   Type="button"   value="help" onClick="javascript:anAus('$button_variable')"/></TD>

</TR>   

<TR id="$button_variable" style="display:none">
        <TD colspan="5" >
<xsl:value-of select = "$verbesserung" /></TD>
</TR>

</tbody>
</TABLE>
```

Now the explanation of my problem:

For each element i generate a row in a html table. Every row has
5 cells. In the last cell is a button, which can expand a help row for the element.

up to now i used a java.script function, that use the elementID of the row-obejct to change the visibility.

i try to generate the button name and objectid by the element id and a string in a
concat operator.
but in my result table every button has the same function, only to expand the "helprow" under the first entry-row.

i tried to give out the "$button_name" and "$button_variable" for each entry and they are correct. can someone find the mistake in the code.

Comment: code looks ok , what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that every button calls the same functionality. they always call the visibility for help row 1.

i looked on the result html and the '$button_name' and '$button_variable' are not used with their values, but with their names. like this : <input onclick="javascript:anAus('$button_variable')" value="help" name="$button_name" type="button"></td>

Comment: i've updated my answer, check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your last `td` like this:

```
<TD width="50" align="center">
   <input name="$button_name"   Type="button"   value="help" >
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">javascript:anAus('<xsl:value-of select="$button_variable" />')</xsl:attribute>
   </input>
</TD>
```

And your hidden `tr` like this:

```
<TR style="display:none">
   <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$button_variable" /></xsl:attribute>
   <TD colspan="5" >
     <xsl:value-of select = "$verbesserung" />
   </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: okay this is what i searched for. is there a reason why firefox 23 cant work with this? only IE do the transformation.

Comment: @Logi you can google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+xslt&oq=firefox+xslt&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8